# Overcome lint warning: custodial pointer has not been freed or returned

Tags: c, lint

I have a simple C code where I pass by reference like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(int *a)
{
    *a = 12;
}

int main()
{
    int a=10;
    printf("%d\n",a);
    fun(&a);
    printf("%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Lint throws:

```
error:custodial pointer 'a' has not been freed or returned.
```

I don't want to suppress lint warning; I rather want to avoid the error. This symbol `a` remains custodial until it is passed to another function. Here I am not passing it to another function. Also it can't be freed, as I am accessing its reference from `main()`. How to overcome this lint warning?

Comment: It isn't clear what `lint` is complaining about — there isn't a problem that I see in the code.  You'll need to study your `lint` manual and see how it recommends you fix the issue — and how it explains what the issue (because, as I said, I don't see any problem with the code).

Comment: [Here's a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3887901/3386109). If I'm reading that answer correctly, then I think you should file a bug report.